# gdal_translate gives "FAILURE: No target dataset specified." error

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate

I want to reduce the size of a GeoTIFF to 10% of it's original size. Here's the command I tried:

```
gdal_translate -outsize 10% orig.tif orig-small.tif
```

When I run that command, however, I get this error:

```
FAILURE: No target dataset specified.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is orig.tif in your current directory? Perhaps try (on Windows) gdal_translate -of GTIFF -outsize 10% .\orig.tif .\orig-small.tif to assert the output is in the current directory.

Comment: @MichaelStimson - yah - orig.tif is in the current directory. It's a 14.7GB, if that makes a difference (a BigTIFF). I tried adding `-of GTIFF` and adding .\ before the source and target filenames without success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the `ysize[%]|0` component of the [`-outsize` argument](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#cmdoption-gdal_translate-outsize).  The syntax is:

```
gdal_translate -outsize xsize[%]|0 ysize[%]|0 src_dataset dst_dataset
```

Where:

> `-outsize <xsize>[%]|0 <ysize>[%]|0`
>
> Set the size of the output file. Outsize is in pixels and lines unless ‘%’ is attached in which case it is as a fraction of the input image size. If one of the 2 values is set to 0, its value will be determined from the other one, while maintaining the aspect ratio of the source dataset.

So gdal_translate thinks `orig.tif` is `ysize`, `orig-small.tif` is the `src_dataset` and therefore there's no `dst_dataset` argument, hence the `No target dataset specified` error...

So use:

```
gdal_translate -outsize 10% 10% orig.tif orig-small.tif
# Or
gdal_translate -outsize 10% 0 orig.tif orig-small.tif
```